# drawRect in SKScene

Tags: sprite-kit, drawrect, uibezierpath

I am trying to use a UIBezier path for drawing a line using user touch. I have the physics body and bezier working separately although I need to merge them together. Is there a way to implement drawRect or an equivalent within SpriteKit? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. DrawRect or other custom drawing methods are not (currently) supported by Sprite Kit. Use SKShapeNode to draw the path.

```
SKShapeNode* shape = [SKShapeNode node];

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
// create your path here ...

shape.path = path;
[self addChild:shape];
```

Comment: If you know how to make a diagonal SKShapeNode line then that solves the problem. Thanks for the start!

Comment: @TimothySwan what do you mean? Are you trying to put objective-c code into swift??

Comment: Right. I finally realize that was the issue after making some corrections.